# Non-Selective Query Error but I am Using IDs

Tags: query, error

I am receiving an error when trying to add a chatter comment. I have a system of classes and 2 triggers that send a custom email notification when a chatter post has been added to a case or when a comment has been added to a chatter post. The handler and gateway for the FeedItems seems to be working fine, but I get an error when adding a comment to a chatter post. The error says: "Non-Selective Query against a large object type (more than 10000 rows). The query in my code that is throwing this error is:

```
 User itemOwner = [select id, Email, Case_Chatter_Email_Notifications__c From User where id IN (select CreatedById From FeedItem Where Id =: feedItemId )];

 return itemOwner;
```

Since I am using IDs, I am having a difficult time determining why this query is non-selective. Any input on where I should be looking would be greatly helpful.